# pass/display choice chip string value in flutter

Tags: flutter

How can i choose from a choice chip and pass that selected string value to a screen or text widget?

I found this code online and how can i pass the selected value

```
    Widget _buildChips() {
    List<Widget> chips = new List();

    for (int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++) {
      ChoiceChip choiceChip = ChoiceChip(
        selected: _selectedIndex == i,
        label: Text(_options[i], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        elevation: 3,
        pressElevation: 5,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
        selectedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
        onSelected: (bool selected) {
          setState(() {
            if (selected) {
              _selectedIndex = i;
            }
          });
        },
      );
      chips.add(choiceChip);

    }
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: chips,
    );

  }
```

and this is the implementation

```
    int _selectedIndex;
  List<String> _options = ['Regular', 'Hard Sleeper', 'Soft Sleeper'];
```

you can show me another way to do this too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `_options[_selectedIndex]` 
code snippet

```
  Text(
    '${_options[_selectedIndex]}',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
  ),
  RaisedButton(
    child: Text('Open route'),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SecondRoute(
                  selectedValue: _options[_selectedIndex],
                )),
      );
    },
  ),
...
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  final String selectedValue;

  SecondRoute({this.selectedValue});
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex;
  List<String> _options = ['Regular', 'Hard Sleeper', 'Soft Sleeper'];

  Widget _buildChips() {
    List<Widget> chips = new List();

    for (int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++) {
      ChoiceChip choiceChip = ChoiceChip(
        selected: _selectedIndex == i,
        label: Text(_options[i], style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        elevation: 3,
        pressElevation: 5,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
        selectedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
        onSelected: (bool selected) {
          setState(() {
            if (selected) {
              _selectedIndex = i;
            }
          });
        },
      );
      chips.add(choiceChip);
    }
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: chips,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildChips(),
            _selectedIndex == null
                ? Container()
                : Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '${_options[_selectedIndex]}',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text('Open route'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => SecondRoute(
                                      selectedValue: _options[_selectedIndex],
                                    )),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  final String selectedValue;

  SecondRoute({this.selectedValue});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("$selectedValue"),
        ),
        body: Center(child: Text("$selectedValue")));
  }
}
```