# Flutter: Pass value of multiple (single value) ChoiceChip

Tags: flutter, user-interface

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64777675/pass-display-choice-chip-string-value-in-flutter) is for single ChoiceChip

multiple ChoiceChip is needed but the index (selected) is always same

Below is the code:
It seems it need another variable to store the desired values, but not sure where to start (maybe use provider?)

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget _buildChips(options) {
    List<Widget> chips = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      ChoiceChip choiceChip = ChoiceChip(
        selected: _selectedIndex == i,
        label: Text(options[i], style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        elevation: 3,
        pressElevation: 5,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
        selectedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
        onSelected: (bool selected) {
          setState(() {
            if (selected) {
              _selectedIndex = i;
            }
          });
        },
      );
      chips.add(choiceChip);
    }
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: chips,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Select A value'),
            _buildChips(['Regular', 'Hard Sleeper', 'Soft Sleeper']),
            const Text('Select B value'),
            _buildChips(['Python', 'Flutter']),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Pass selected A and B values to next screen'),
              onPressed: () {print(_selectedIndex);},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use get package and GetXController

https://pub.dev/packages/get

```dart
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Get.put(ChipController());
        return GetBuilder(builder: (ChipController controller) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(widget.title),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text('Select A value'),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: controller.lstType
                        .map((text) => ChoiceChip(
                              selected: controller.selectedChipAData == text,
                              label: Text(text,
                                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                              elevation: 3,
                              pressElevation: 5,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
                              selectedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                              onSelected: (bool selected) {
                                if (selected) {
                                  controller.setSelectedData(text);
                                }
                              },
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                  const Text('Select B value'),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: controller.lstLanguage
                        .map((text) => ChoiceChip(
                              selected: controller.selectedChipBData == text,
                              label: Text(text,
                                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                              elevation: 3,
                              pressElevation: 5,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
                              selectedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                              onSelected: (bool selected) {
                                if (selected) {
                                  controller.setSelectedChipBData(text);
                                }
                              },
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child:
                        const Text('Pass selected A and B values to next screen'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print(controller.selectedChipAData);
                      print(controller.selectedChipBData);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
      }
    }

    class ChipController extends GetxController {
      String? selectedChipAData;
      String? selectedChipBData;
      List<String> lstType = [
        "Regular",
        "Hard Sleeper",
        "Soft Sleeper",
      ];
      List<String> lstLanguage = [
        "Python",
        "Flutter",
      ];
      void setSelectedData(String data) {
        selectedChipAData = data;
        update();
      }

      void setSelectedChipBData(String data) {
        selectedChipBData = data;
        update();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Will check this method. By the way, do you happen to have solution using flutter native provider/multiprovider?

Comment: Of course @DollyStorey you can see my github project.https://github.com/Kyilwinoo007/multi_select_chip_flutter

Comment: @Kti, Thanks it works.  Code can be improve by making one of the chipChoice = True (selected) by default